After banning UNRWA from operating in Gaza, what is the Israeli plan for education in the strip?
AP, October 29, 2024

One of the bills passed Monday evening bans all UNRWA activities and services on Israeli soil and is set to take effect in three months.


The second bill severs all ties between government employees and UNRWA and strips its staff of their legal immunities.


Together, the bills likely bar the agency from operating in Israel and the Palestinian territories, because Israel controls access to both Gaza and the West Bank. It could force the agency to relocate its headquarters from Israeli-annexed east Jerusalem.


The agency is the major distributor of aid in Gaza and provides education, health and other basic services to millions of Palestinian refugees across the region, including in the Israeli-occupied West Bank.

Note: this question is strictly limited to education.
(This question is concerned with the future after a ceasefire.  Running schools is not that realistic right now.)
In the past, Israel has indicated strong disquiet with the format of education, under UNRWA, to Palestinians, claiming that schoolbooks encourage hatred of Israelis.
Now, Israel seems to understand that something needs to take over from UNRWA:

"UNRWA workers involved in terrorist activities against Israel must be held accountable," the office of Israeli Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu said on social media hours after the Knesset vote. "Since avoiding a humanitarian crisis is also essential, sustained humanitarian aid must remain available in Gaza now and in the future. In the 90 days before this legislation takes effect — and after — we stand ready to work with our international partners to ensure Israel continues to facilitate humanitarian aid to civilians in Gaza in a way that does not threaten Israel's security.

How will education be provided in the future?
Education is not like food, or medicine.  It can't just handed over at the border.
Those alleged (but likely) inflammatory teachings in books and classroom speech were - allegedly - provided by UNRWA, a theoretically neutral UN agency.  They in turn claim a lot of their alleged anti-Israel bias was imposed by Hamas, as a cost of "doing business" in Gaza.
What is going to replace UNRWA schooling then?  Anything run more directly by the locals is likely to be even more critical of Israel.  Even a thorough editorial review/censorship of school books being used won't stop teachers from verbal indoctrination, should they choose to.
And putting pro-Israel, or at least really neutral, teachers or supervisors in the schools (either locals or "international partners") would put those people in great danger under the foreseeable circumstances (i.e. a ceasefire, but no durable peace, in Gaza).
What's the Israeli plan then?  What's going to ensure neutrality at the point of delivery, since that was the issue in the first place, education-wise.
p.s. No, this question is not about funding.  It is about Israeli plans to fix the UNRWA's alleged bias, while still providing education.
p.p.s. (in response to a comment about secrecy) These laws were passed in the Knesset and I assume arrangements for providing replacement services were debated there, under no seal of secrecy.

Much details about Israeli Gaza future governance is being kept secret for now so IDK how reasonable it is to expect an answer to this Q, other than based on speculation/analogy.

@IVFcomesfromthetip Well, maybe it'll show up later then.  It doesn't have to be answered right now.  But typically, when a government shuts down a department doing something critical it communicates plans to replaces it with something else (heck that even saved poor Obamacare from Clever Trump).  Was this not discussed in the Knesset?  Are those debates top secret?

Hey folks, I didn't ask this question as an enabler of derogative comments on Israel.  That's not what the comment system is about.   If you have a comment that only consists of the-plan-is-to-screw-the-children, you can always put it as an answer, where it will be up and downvoted as people see fit, but, as a comment, I am highly likely to flag it.  If you think that there is no great plan at this time (which will of course be negative to the children if it remains that way), explain why, provide sources, and put it as an answer.

For clarification, from Israel's perspective, Gaza is not part of Israeli soil and therefore the ban on UNRWA does not apply to Gaza directly? There are only indirect effects as international UNRWA staff may not be able to physically get to Gaza if they can't pass through Israel.

How'd you arrive at "banning UNRWA from operating in Gaza"? The source you quoted only says it bans UNRWA from operating on Israeli territory - unless Israel considers Gaza Israeli territory?

@Allure Israel controls all borders to the strip and the West Bank, including sea access to Gaza.  Press coverage, and Western governments' concerns, assume pretty much that UNRWA is therefore banned from both.  As stated in my comment to Obie: it would make no sense to ban them and then allow them to operate in Gaza, because that means, from an Israeli PoV, UNRWA would get even less oversight than before.

You can ask about "expressed" or "stated" plan.  But asking about a plan at large is bound to invite speculation.

Frame challenge. UNRWA was apparently  not banned in Gaza:

“After the bill passes, UNRWA can work in Gaza and the West Bank, although it will not be able to operate in Israel,” and the borders between Israel, Gaza and the West Bank “will be closed to them,” the spokesman explained, adding dryly that UNRWA staffers “can use parachutes” to get in.

That last bit seems to refer to international staff. Most the UNRWA teachers were locals AFAICT, so they do not seem directly affected by this law, except possibly pay-wise.
FWTW, the person who introduced the bills did not address what if anything would replace or supplement UNRWA should they have problems due to these bills.

Knesset Foreign Affairs and Defense Committee chairman MK Yuli Edelstein presented both bills in the plenum. [...]
Edelstein did not address in his speech who would replace the services UNRWA provides for Palestinians in east Jerusalem, Gaza, and the West Bank.
After the bills passed, Edelstein called the bills “historic” and the “elimination of one of the arms of terror that acted under UN auspices.”

... except in East Jerusalem, where Israeli ministries will take over, according to one of the drafters -- MK Dan Illouz. For the rest of the OPT, the issue was apparently not discussed.

One of the bill’s authors, MK Dan Illouz (Likud), said the Jerusalem Ministry had plans in place to take over UNRWA’s responsibilities in east Jerusalem. The ministry said in response to a query that regarding education, the ministry and Jerusalem Municipality are acting to create “alternative education sites in the immediate time range,” and “founding permanent educational institutions in the long run.”

Or if it was somehow discussed (for Gaza) the discussion was not found newsworthy by either JP's pretty long article (that I quoted the above from), or by ToI's coverage of the passage of these bills.
BTW, the OP commented below that this doesn't make sense. To me it does somewhat.
Israel's government is internally quite divided on what to do with Gaza "the day after" fighting stops (if ever). So they can easily agree they don't want Hamas & UNRWA (nor the Palestinian Authority), but not much else in this regard.

I wonder if that official might have been a lil' bit sarcastic. Israel is monitoring the aerial space above Gaza and parachuting staffers has not been their priority.

Parachutes are not that realistic, but boats might be (or cooperating with Egypt to cross there). Has the Israeli government indicated whether it plans to impede these methods after whatever resolution to the war Netanyahu's government imagines? If so, then this is a de facto ban. If not, it might just make things harder.

Nah, this doesn't make all that much sense.  If the point was to fix UNRWA bias, what would allowing them to continue operating in Gaza, but with even less control over their access achieve?

My comment about not making sense was concerning Obie's hypothesis about other border arrangements.  This answer is looking more solid now that it has been expanding to claim that there probably is not much of a plan (yet?) and that there wasn't a big push to define replacement education arrangements, especially on the last paragraph, stating that they "can't agree on much".

@Obie2.0 Boats are not realistic. Gaza is under a complete blockade by Israel, including the border with Egypt (Philadelphi corridor).

@VladimirFГероямслав - Yes, Israel has been blocking the arrival of boats for a long time; further, before the war, Egypt already blocked the Philadelphi corridor, and as of May of this year, Israel has taken control of it and is blocking it from the other side. None of that is in dispute; however, the question and particularly the answer are about whether some teachers might be allowed to enter Gaza after the war (whether this is true or not is quite another question!). Under that supposition, arriving by boat, say, is a realistic proposal, whereas jumping out of a plane is not.

Not that I particularly believe it likely that Israel will be inclined to allow boats with UNRWA employees through the blockade in the future, nor even that Egypt would let them cross from the north if they took over again. But still, that's part of the question, isn't it: does the Israeli government indeed intend to prevent these methods after the war is over or not?

@ItalianPhilosopher - While I tend to agree, nor can I dismiss the possibility that there are factions within the Israeli government that want the UNRWA as a boogeyman and to be seen to be taking strong actions against it, but at the same time see it as in their best interest to have it do the dirty work of infrastructure in Gaza/have it around to blame for anything that goes wrong (isn't the hypothesis that Netanyahu thought something similar about Hamas, even?)

I'll probably end up accepting this for now a bit later.  Hopefully, I'll have to change over my acceptance when an actual plan arrives and someone answers on that basis.

Sorry to get political on the Politics StackExchange, but, another frame challenge...
There is no Israeli plan for education in the Gaza Strip because:

The Israeli plan is to commit genocide
The Israeli government does not have consensus on what education will look like in the Gaza Strip (see IVF comes from the tip's answer)

Reasoning
Israel is perpetrating a genocide in Gaza. In July this year, the death toll was estimated to be 186,000, by no stretch of the imagination a proportionate response to Oct 7. The vast majority of UN member states have called for an immediate ceasefire. The ICC considers accusations of genocide plausible and Israeli ministers continuously engage in genocidal rhetoric. Respectable NGOs such as Doctors Without Borders, OHCHR, Human Rights Watch, and UNRWA itself are near unanimous in condemning Israeli violence.
Given this, Israel's clear intent is to destroy Palestinian life in the Gaza Strip. The "Israeli plan for education in the strip" must be understood in this context. The Israeli government may have different ideas about what education might look like, but I would argue that there is no meaningful plan. The only plan is extermination, apartheid, and settlement.

TBF, there's no agreement on settling Gaza for now, even though about a third of Likud MPs (and more in the farther-right parties) support that option. It is part of the deadlock/gridlock in the ruling coalition regarding "the day after". https://www.timesofisrael.com/it-is-doable-10-likud-mks-to-attend-conference-calling-for-resettling-gaza/

That Lancet article, if correc, is at most indicative of extremely high long term mortality.  Which, honestly, the international community should put a lot more pressure on Israel about.  But that's leap to saying that there is an active plan for genocide.  A plan which apparently wasn't discussed at the legistlative session the UNRWA was passed at which is what I was asking about. Making the rest of this answer rather speculative.

@ItalianPhilosopher - I think the first comment is basically correct: there are a lot of factions even within the current right-wing Israeli government, ranging from people who basically do want to kill all Palestinians (these people could fairly be described as genocidal) to people who to people who would prefer to expel Palestinians (ethnic cleansing, but not necessarily genocide) to people don't particularly care how many Palestinians die in the course of killing as many Hamas members as possible (still war crimes, though).

@ItalianPhilosopher - E.g. if one reads this article,  the finance minister Bezalel Smotrich basically wants everyone in the Gaza Strip to die so that Israel can take it over and repopulate it, but Netanyahu doesn't think that is possible (lest he come across as moral here, he still is quite willing to accept or even seek vast civilian casualties in the war).

So Smotrich and Netanyahu probably have very different ideas of what education in the Gaza Strip should look like. Smotrich probably does think something more like this answer—that all the Palestinians should be expelled or killed anyway, so why bother thinking about it? Netanyahu—well, based on Likud's plans for East Jerusalem, he might be thinking of an Israeli-controlled (propagandistic) education ministry in the Gaza Strip.

@Obie2.0 All very valid points, about Smotrich and Ben-Gvir.  But are they representative of a concerted plan by the Israeli state/Knesset, as a whole, to effect  those policies?  What is the public support for actual genocide and ethnic cleansing?  This answer just waves that around as a given.  Thing is, to me it seems that Israelis are traumatized, find it hard to have rational political debates where people speak of those risks (hence "well, no one thought of that" in ever-changing-username's answer) and end up with a slow moving disaster of a non-policy...

... akin to what we saw with food supplies before they were forced/shamed by outsiders to somewhat adjust their policies.  Policies which had been hijacked by Smotrich - a dude with what, 7% of Knesset seats?  Add to it an outsized regional military capability and an enemy (Hamas) willing to expand civilian lives as cheaply as bullets (not least by not surrendering to halt combats) and you have a recipe for massive civilian mortality.  But to smear the whole country with intent of genocide - which is what this answer does, without proof - is not something I condone.
